# jQuery instantly executes (a button click and css change) on load

Tags: plugin-development, jquery

I am following this other thread to get jQuery into my admin settings page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28248113/jquery-is-not-defined-in-wordpress-but-my-script-is-enqueued-properly

My settings page building function:

```
function buildSettingsPage() {
  require 'views/newCouponForm.php'; // pure html

  wp_enqueue_media();
  wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
  ?>

  <button>Test</button>

  <script>
    (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button").click().css("color", "orange");
      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>

  <continues... removed>
```

The button instantly appears with orange text and submits, causing the page to go white after a second. I see the url with query string parameters also at this point. I believe this means a post request (which I haven't handled yet) is executed.

When I comment the IIFE the problem goes away.

How can I prevent this behavior? The intended behavior is to have the button text turn orange and submit on click only.

Attempted:

```
  <script>
    (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("button").click().css("color", "orange");
      });
    })(jQuery);
  </script>


Uncaught TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (options-general.php?page=fvc-settings:304)
    at i (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=5.1.1:2)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.click()` function triggers a click. This is why this is happening. After the click `.css()` runs and turns the button orange.

If you want to change the colour on click then, as clear from [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/click/), the event handler needs to be passed as a callback function to `.click()`, not chained to it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).css("color", "orange");
    });
});
```

Note that `e.preventDefault();` is supposed to go in the event handler, not where you had it.

Also, I think it's worth pointing out that jQuery is unecessary for this, you can do it with 'vanilla' JS like so:

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll( 'button' );

for ( var i = 0; i < buttons .length; i++ ) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener( 'click', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        buttons[i].style.color = 'orange';
    }
}
```

Or, if you don't need to support IE:

```
document.querySelectorAll( 'button' ).forEach( function( el ) {
    el.addEventListener( 'click', function( e ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        el.style.color = 'orange';
    }
} );
```